# Incorrect creating date object in javascript via "new Date()" in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date, creation

The problem manifests irregularly and only occurs in Chrome. 
During the creation of the date object in JavaScript via `new Date("..some date time string..")`, it occasionally returns the date incorrectly as `6 Sep 2013 12:28:48 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`. I investigated all of the source code and did not find this date anywhere. I attempted to create the date object via all accessible constructors, but was getting the same incorrect result occasionally. Then, I created the date object via `Date.parse()`, which appears to always work correctly.

[image]
[image]

It happened very rarely. 
Browser cache had cleared in time on. 
This can occur for any date and time string.
userAgent string: `"Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT6.2;WOW64)AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML,likeGecko)Chrome/29.0.1547.76Safari/537.36"`

Answer (score 1):

That's unusual. The date parsing functions are implementation dependent, so they may interpret date strings differently. But the issue you're having seems to suggest that Date.parse() uses a different implementation than the function that gets called by the new Date() constructor, when in fact they should be the same.

See the following posts:

- [How does javascripts date work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13659149/how-does-javascripts-date-work)
- [new Date works differently in chrome and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109894/new-date-works-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox)